# Datasets in ColdFusion and cfprocresult

Tags: stored-procedures, coldfusion, dataset

I was wondering if there is a way to use cfprocresult as dataset in c#. I have SP that returns two tables, i want to put that tables in cfprocresult. Is that possible, and how? Example:

```
 <cfprocresult name="qResult">
```

And now i want to do this

```
  qResult.Table1
  qResult.Table2
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question makes very little sense. What has C# got to do with calling procs in ColdFusion?

Ignoring the C# reference, `<cfprocresult>` takes a `resultset` attribute which specifies which resultset from the proc return value goes in which variable, eg:

```
<cfprocresult resultset="1" name="table1">
<cfprocresult resultset="2" name="table2">
```

The docs for [`<cfprocresult>`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfprocresult) explain it all. It's always best to RTFM before asking a question about how code works.

Comment: I mentioned c# and dataset only for easier understanding of my question. I am new to coldfusion, but i have experience in c# so i used it to explain what i desire to accomplish in CF.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a cfprocresult for each table in the return.  Those then become their own query object that can be handled separately.

```
<cfprocresult name = "result1" resultSet = "1">
<cfprocresult name = "result2" resultSet = "2">
```